# PyTorch tutorial using testing dataset in training epoch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, training-data, train-test-split

In PyTorch official tutorial: [OPTIMIZING MODEL PARAMETERS](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/optimization_tutorial.html#optimization-loop). The dataset is said to be split into training data and testing data. However, the testing dataset was used in each epoch.

Shouldn't the testing dataset only be used once for the evaluating the final model? Or in this tutorial the 'testing dataset' is actually 'validation dataset' and there is no testing dataset in the code?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed in many basic ML/DL tutorials, the fine distinction between validation and test is often overlooked. In the tutorial you mentioned, since no "decision" is made based on the validation performance (e.g., early stopping), this set can be considered a "test" set and it is okay to monitor test performance during training.